# Best way to provide custom view for selected list item

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

Goal : have completely custom layout for selected item, considering only single item can be selected at a time.

I do not want to involve `getViewTypeCount`/`getItemViewType` for selection as they are already used in this adapter for different purposes.

One obvious option is inflating custom layout to indicate selected item by modifying adapter to something like :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;
         ... 
         // initialize convertView, holder, regular stuff

         // Now, the questionable part:

        if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
           // use custom layout to indicate highlight/selection
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_selection_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            // clear up selection 
            // also convertView could be recycled view and be of unexpected type 
        }
    }
```

It shouldn't be too bad performance-wise as only single item is selected/inflated, but the problem is that `convertedView` can be of two different types, and extra cast/checks are needed. 
*Is this approach is frowned upon ?*

Another option could be : have both selected/unselected version of layout combined in `item_layout` and one of them hidden/shown in adapter dynamically depending on `if (position == mSelectedPosition)` condition.
*Is this a good idea ?*

Ultimately, what would be the right way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the first approach. Your custom layout should be applied to only one view in the entire list, so the only thing you need to do is to avoid that such view can be recycled. I'm using this approach to load dividers at specific points in the list, and I see no performance issues.

On the other hand, having - let's say so - both layouts in one and change visibilities seems not the best option to me, as your view holder would become quite big (you need to carry reference of *all* the views inside, I guess) to the benefit of just a single child in the whole list. All the recycled, non-selected views would each time face the position check, that would be unnecessary for most (all but one) cases.

---

As for identifying the view once it gets recycled, a possible approach is to use tags as well.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_selection_layout, parent, false);
       //here you upload convertView without the ViewHolder pattern, by using findViewById();
       //it's legit IMO because it gets called just once for the whole list.
       convertView.setTag("SELECTED_VIEW");
       return convertView;
    }

     ViewHolder holder;
     if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag("SELECTED_VIEW")) {
         //this convertView is not good. We inflate the regular layout
         convertView = inflater.inflate( ... );
     }

     //regular stuff
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `... is to avoid that such view can be recycled` - how do you do that ?

Comment: Gave you some clues in edited answer. Certainly this is not the only approach. E.g., if you highlighted view layout has a different root class, you could check with `instanceof` to separate regular and highlighted views.

Comment: I got really interested when you mentioned : `avoid that such view can be recycled`, could you please share how you do that in your above mentioned apparoch ? In your sample above it IS recycled, you just avoid using wrong view with the tag (nice approach btw).

Comment: Nope, you can't avoid the wrong view to be passed in as a parameter for `getView`. As far as I know. I was meaning "avoid that such view can be shown after recycling".

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, I just found that apparently it is possible to avoid recycling of certain view altogether by using : [IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE). Haven't tried it though.

Comment: anyways, Thanks for sharing your thoughts and experience with that, +1 and accepted.

Comment: Will check it out. At the time I thought about setting a RecyclerListener also, but that gets called hundreds of times.

Comment: Feel free to share your experience with that, I don't want to use getItemViewType that would be needed for that and will go with your approach for now. Thanks again.